# web3.eth.personal.sign with WalletConnect and Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect

I'm developing a dapps that uses `web3.eth.personal.sign` to sign data from users. The problem is, when I use Gnosis Safe with WalletConnect, the value received from the function is just "0x" instead of the full signature.

Are there any ways to get the data from the `web3.eth.personal.sign` with Gnosis Safe WalletConnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Safe is a smart contract based wallet you will not get a ECDSA signature that can be recovered to a Safe address. The Safe uses [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) to support message signing.

In the current implementation the Safe confirms the message on-chain. Therefore it only returns `0x` as the signature. To check if the message was successfully signed you would use `isValidSignature` (as defined in EIP-1271) to check with the Safe if your specific message/signature combination is valid.