# Validate a message was signed by a gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I feel like I am missing something fairly basic here, hopefully this is a simple answer. I have done a ton of research on validating signatures from a gnosis safe. My safe is performing a transaction to store the fact that a signature was made by the owners on-chain. That part is all good. Now I need to verify the signature from my dApp smart contract and am running into VM execution errors. I decided to try and verify the signature from ethers just as a confirmation and ran into the same issue.

After reading about EIP-1271, my understanding is that safes should implement this EIP by default. I have a basic safe I created at https://gnosis-safe.io/app/ on the gnosis chain, and have signed a message from my dApp using the `safe-apps-provider` which is wrapped into an ethers Provider and then calls `signMessage`. A safe txn is performed to record the signature, and returns `0x` to my dApp which I get means for this signature, I need to query the safe for signature validation, since smart contracts cannot generate ECDSA signatures like an EOA.

So now I am trying to verify the signature. I have the following code that just constructs an ethers `Contract` with just the EIP-1271 ABI so I can call `isValidSignature`. The call results in a VM error which to me, seems like the safe does not have the `isValidSignature` method. I could not find anywhere in the gnosis UI to enable this - my understanding is this should be enabled by default? I went down a rabbit hole looking at the safe code, but with all the libraries and fallback handlers, I wasn't able to confidently track down where the safe is actually implementing `isValidSignature`. The contract address below is the freshly created safe on gnosis which is version 1.3.0.

Shouldn't this work?

Code:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "hash",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "signature",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "isValidSignature",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes4",
                "name": "magicValue",
                "type": "bytes4"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc.gnosischain.com/')

safe = new ethers.Contract('0x22207860a2e5a50941c7ED99d20a18ADeCC93846', abi, provider);

msgHash = '0x220964afc8696c1bedbc4045ded3e62edca1bf83518f20121cfaf20347223d0b'; // message hash signed by safe

await safe.isValidSignature(msgHash, '0x');
```

and this results in VM execution errors:

```
Uncaught:
Error: missing revert data in call exception (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"code\":-32015,\"message\":\"VM execution error.\",\"data\":\"Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564\"},\"id\":44}","error":{"code":-32015,"data":"Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564"},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0x22207860a2e5a50941c7ed99d20a18adecc93846\",\"data\":\"0x1626ba7e220964afc8696c1bedbc4045ded3e62edca1bf83518f20121cfaf20347223d0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://rpc.gnosischain.com/"}, data="0x", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.5.3)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
    at checkError (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:76:16)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:659:47)
    at step (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23) {
  reason: 'missing revert data in call exception',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"code\":-32015,\"message\":\"VM execution error.\",\"data\":\"Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564\"},\"id\":44}", error={"code":-32015,"data":"Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564"}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0x22207860a2e5a50941c7ed99d20a18adecc93846\",\"data\":\"0x1626ba7e220964afc8696c1bedbc4045ded3e62edca1bf83518f20121cfaf20347223d0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://rpc.gnosischain.com/", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.5.1)
      at Logger.makeError (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
      at Logger.throwError (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
      at /Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:301:32
      at step (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32015,"message":"VM execution error.","data":"Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564"},"id":44}',
    error: Error: VM execution error.
        at getResult (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:142:21)
        at processJsonFunc (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:344:22)
        at /Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:276:46
        at step (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (/Users/masha/Projects/contracts/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: -32015,
      data: 'Reverted 0x48617368206e6f7420617070726f766564'
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x22207860a2e5a50941c7ed99d20a18adecc93846","data":"0x1626ba7e220964afc8696c1bedbc4045ded3e62edca1bf83518f20121cfaf20347223d0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'https://rpc.gnosischain.com/'
  },
  data: '0x'
}
```

Comment: The revert here means the message was not signed

Comment: That message hash is directly pulled from the SignMsg event that was triggered when it was signed.

Comment: Safe performs additional hashing for security measurements, you should use the original hash of your message

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/130345/102891) how to validate the signature of a Gnosis Safe using ethers.js.

For me, the following code works:

```
import { Contract, utils, ethers } from "ethers";
...
const abi = ['function isValidSignature(bytes32 _message, bytes _signature) public view returns (bytes4)'];
const walletContract = new Contract("0xE1...", abi, provider);
let msg = "Your message";
let sig = "0x";
const hashMessage = utils.hashMessage(msg);
const response = await walletContract.isValidSignature(hashMessage, sig);

// Verify if the response matches the EIP-1271 magic value '0x1626ba7e'
...
```

To answer your questions:

1. isValidSignature() is enabled by default on Gnosis Safe.
2. [This](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/da66b45ec87d2fb6da7dfd837b29eacdb9a604c5/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L66) should be the contract code that is called.