# Error signing message with SIWE using WalletConnect V2 with Gnosis Safe wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect

I'm currently using **@web3-react/walletconnect-v2** for my Dapp.

When the user copies the WalletConnect link to Gnosis Safe to try to connect to my Dapp,it says connected on Gnosis Safe site.

But on our end, we got an error message when trying to verify the sign message from the Gnosis Safe wallet using **SiweMessage.verify**:

```
error: {type: "Signature do not match address of the message.",...}
```

What should I do to make the verification works?

Comment: It seem that there's an error when SIWE checks the ERC-1271 signature provided by Gnosis Safe (error should be thrown here: https://github.com/spruceid/siwe/blob/e3ca3cebddeff7707baa8826ce7524c27cd7595a/packages/siwe/lib/client.ts#L338).


The signature should be just "0x" and isValidSignature should return ERC-1271's magic value (see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/130345/102891). 

Can you debug the workflow and check if these values align?