# Integrating EIP-1271 with Safe SDK for Signature Verification

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, eip-1271

I'm working on implementing signature verification using the Safe SDK in conjunction with EIP-1271. Currently, I'm referring to [this documentation](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/docs/signatures.md) for initializing my application with EIP-1271.

I have a few questions regarding the integration:

1. **Using EIP-1271 with Safe SDK**: Is it possible to implement EIP-1271 directly through the protocol kit, or should I opt for a web3 library that interfaces with SafeFactory?
2. **execTransaction Function**: The `execTransaction` function mentioned in the documentation - is this a built-in function within the SDK, or is it a separate function in the Smart Contract Wallet (SCW) for manually executing transactions outside the SDK?

Any insights or references to related projects that have integrated EIP-1271 with Safe would be immensely helpful. I'm looking to understand the best practices and nuances of this integration.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

eth

1. Yes, since Safe supports EIP-1271 natively, you should be able to check if a message is correctly signed directly from the [protocol kit](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/b369f75df9f1c0c5a6415f212a597b858566378c/packages/protocol-kit/src/adapters/ethers/contracts/SignMessageLib/SignMessageLibEthersContract.ts).
2. `execTransaction` function is a function from the smart contract that you can call directly (without the SDK), however the SDK has its equivalent, [`executeTransaction`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/b369f75df9f1c0c5a6415f212a597b858566378c/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L989).

Some more context here: [GnosisSafe: Signing and verifying a signature](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/gnosissafe-signing-and-verifying-a-signature)

Hope it helps!
Louis